# pass value from listview to textbox

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have been trying to work this out all day and posted a question which got me this far. I cannot get the listview value to my textboxes in the add sub when I click an entry in listview. It is driving me nuts and to that end would be grateful if someone could point out my error. Thanks

Need to populate these textboxes

```
Sub add()
        Try
            While dr.Read()
                txtname.Text = dr(0)
                txtfathername.Text = dr(1)
                txtaddress.Text = dr(2)
                txtemail.Text = dr(3)
            End While
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Listview code

```
Sub filllistview()
        Try
            'creatconn()
            cn.Open()
            Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("Select * from Postings", cn)
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            While dr.Read()

                ListView1.Items.Add(dr(0).ToString())
                ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(dr(1).ToString())
                ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(dr(2).ToString())
                ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(dr(3).ToString())

            End While

        Catch ex As Exception
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Finally
            dr.Close()
            cn.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have any error? What is exactly the problem?

Comment: The listview click related code would be helpful

Comment: @Plutonix. Sorry my bad posted the wrong question. This was part of an earlier question. Disregard. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
  Private Sub lstPosting_MouseClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles lstPosting.MouseClick
       Textbox1.Text = lstPosting.SelectedItems.Item(0).Text
   End Sub
```

Comment: Perhaps you could explain what is going on in your code, to help others.